# how to fix error for laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

i have a work on create custom driver in laravel 5.2.My code is below here.

my auth.php has

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'bootsgrid',

    ],
```

And my app.php have

```
        App\Bootsgrid\Authentication\AuthServiceProvider::class,
```

my custom driver controller below there

```
<?php
namespace App\Bootsgrid\Authentication;
use Auth;
 use App\Bootsgrid\Authentication\UserProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
 {
/**
 * Perform post-registration booting of services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Auth::provider('bootsgrid', function($app, array $config) {
        return new UserProvider();
    });
}
/**
 * Register bindings in the container.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}
}
```

And my provider file there

```
<?php
 namespace App\Bootsgrid\Authentication;
use App\Bootsgrid\Authentication\User;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider as IlluminateUserProvider;



class UserProvider implements IlluminateUserProvider
 {

/**
 * @param  mixed  $identifier
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
 */
public function retrieveById($identifier)
{
            // Get and return a user by their unique identifier
}
/**
 * @param  mixed   $identifier
 * @param  string  $token
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
 */
public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
{
    // Get and return a user by their unique identifier and "remember me" token
}
/**
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
 * @param  string  $token
 * @return void
 */
public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token)
{

    // Save the given "remember me" token for the given user
}
/**
 * Retrieve a user by the given credentials.
 *
 * @param  array  $credentials
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
 */
public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
{

    // Get and return a user by looking up the given credentials
}
/**
 * Validate a user against the given credentials.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
 * @param  array  $credentials
 * @return bool
 */
public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)
{
    // Check that given credentials belong to the given user
}
}
```

This is all my code but  i got a error below this

```
Declaration of App\Bootsgrid\Authentication\UserProvider::updateRememberToken() must be compatible with Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider::updateRememberToken(Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable $user, $token)
```

i dont know How to fix it.please help me.

Comment: could you put this underneath your namespace declaration: `use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;`. If this doesn't fix it, I'm very interested in what's happening

Comment: ya its fixed .i am very happy to say thank you so much

Comment: I'll add as answer so you can accept it :)

Comment: ya  its correct  i am accepted thank you

Comment: hai are u there

Answer (score 4):

Put this underneath your namespace declaration: `use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;`.

Comment: Thank you very much